# Clear or Disable NetBIOS name caches

Tags: networking, command-line, netbios

I am working with Netbios via C++ code (Windows Netbios API).
I did not find that Netbios API have clear cache function.
In order to clear cache i use the "command line" and run:

```
nbtstat -R
```

1. Is there a way via code to clear netbious cache ? without opening a console (via code..) and do it ?
2. Is there a way in Operation system to permanently disable Netbios cache ?

   [Netbios windows](https://superuser.com/questions/208443/clear-windows-7-network-computer-names-cache)

Comment: I ask if there is an option in Windows, maybe via Control Center, or advanced Powershell command - to disable the Netbios cache, maybe a flag in regedit ?

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://serverfault.com/questions/836361/clear-or-disable-netbios-name-caches). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: how about trying to answer the question ? Is there a way in Operation system to permanently disable Netbios cache

Comment: When you ask an on topic question (on a single site) then someone might answer it.

Comment: Moderator will mark as duplicate if needed - But the chances of this question to be answered is higher, it is better for all users that this question to be answered. You dont know the answer either, and most people dont, when it is posted on both sites - more people will see the question, and when someone answer, we can mark as duplicate and have solution. Sounds to me that you are bored on your sunday vacation.

Comment: You clearly don't understand how duplicates work. You cannot mark questions as a duplicate of one on a different site.

Comment: Your question is still off-topic ...

Comment: Is there a way in Windows Operation system to permanently disable Netbios cache ? I dont want to use bntstat -R

Comment: Need to send IOCTL_NETBT_PURGE_CACHE to the NBT driver, code maybe relevant https://github.com/Paolo-Maffei/OpenNT/blob/master/ds/netapi/svcdlls/browser2/browtest/browfunc.c